# Flask-Socketio is disconnecting web (& python) clients after 15 mins of data streaming

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am building a flask based webapp and after around 15 mins of live streaming (where web page is kept idle/open in Chrome), the web-client and python-client receives a disconnect event from flask server (on socketio client) and after that both clients are reconnected on new instance of flask server, the streaming to UI wont work anymore. Flask server is deployed using eventlet on IIS Manager.

Any inputs on how to proceed please!

More details:
I have separate socketio-client, which picks the live data from another websocket and publish them (after processing) onto socketio using Emit.
Socketio server listens to this particular event and on each such data it updates its internal dictionary with the latest data (lets call it "Curve")

Then there is a Web UI, which on loading emits a message to Socketio server, which triggers a background task to process latest "Curve" data and pushes the updates to socketio on "bedata" topic.
Web UI updates its table on each update received on socketio on "bedata".

The setup works like a charm for ~15 mins, after that both Web UI client and Python socketio-Client receives a "Disconnect" event from Flask and after the though both of them are connected back, the streaming stops and doesn't tick anymore!

WorkFlow:

Python based SocketIO client(DataStreamer.py) => app.py + MydataClient.py  => JS of html (client.html) => GUI (client.html)

****init**.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from threading import Lock
import eventlet

eventlet.monkey_patch()
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./templates')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'privatekey!'

thread = None
thread_lock = Lock
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*',ping_timeout=15,logging=True)
```

**app.py:**

```
from wwwroot.StreamingApp import app, thread, thread_lock, socketio
import MydataClient
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi

wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(("0.0.0.0", 90)), app)

@app.route("/live")
def main():
    return render_template('client.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/web')
def connect():
    print('Client Connected')

@socketio.on('mydata',namespace='/web')
def MsgHandler(data):
    MydataClient.Curve = data
```

**MydataClient.py:**

```
from wwwroot.StreamingApp import app, thread, thread_lock, socketio

Curve=None
def CalculateBE():
    while True:
        response = {'status': True}
        for args in live_be:
            if args == None:
                continue
            be_price = #a method which does calculations on "Curve" data defined above
            response['BE' + str(args[0])] = be_price
        socketio.emit('bedata', response)
        socketio.sleep(5)

@socketio.on('be')
def UpdateBE():
    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(CalculateBE)
```

**client.html **(Following is the code in JS of html):****

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    var flask_socket = io.connect('http://localhost:90');
    flask_socket.on('connect',()=>{
        console.log('connected!');
    });
    flask_socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        console.log('disconnected!');
    });
    flask_socket.emit('be');
    flask_socket.on("bedata", function (response) {
        #Update UI
    });
});
</script>
```

**DataStreamer.py:**

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client(reconnection_attempts=5,reconnection_delay=2,reconnection_delay_max=10)
sio.on('connect', on_connect)
sio.on('disconnect', on_disconnect)
sio.on('reconnect', on_reconnect)
sio.connect('http://localhost:90',namespaces=['/web'])
#some calculations from websocket data and then emit
sio.emit("mydata",curve_data,namespace="/web")
```

Following are the versions of pkgs used:

flask:**2.3.2**
flask-socketio:**5.3.5**

python-socketio:**:5.8.0**

DataStreamer.py logs around disconnect:

1. 2023-09-11 14:51:35,158:INFO:client:395 => Emitting event "mydata" [/web]
2. 2023-09-11 14:51:35,549:INFO:client:718 => Engine.IO connection dropped
3. 2023-09-11 14:51:35,564:INFO:client:652 => Connection failed, new attempt in 1.97 seconds
4. 2023-09-11 14:51:36,190:ERROR:_logging:64 => error from callback <function Connection.run..on_message at 0x000001A7C30BC2C0>: /web is not a connected namespace.
5. 2023-09-11 14:51:36,205:INFO:DataStreamer:171 => /web is not a connected namespace.
6. 2023-09-11 14:51:38,096:INFO:client:681 => Engine.IO connection established
7. 2023-09-11 14:51:38,143:INFO:client:562 => Namespace /web is connected
8. 2023-09-11 14:51:38,174:INFO:client:669 => Reconnection successful

Answer (score 0):

Disconnections can happen for a lot of different reasons that are external to the actual server and client, so I'm going to assume that this is something that cannot be helped and that your goal is to figure out how to resume streaming once the clients are reconnected.

Looking at your log, the `/web is not a connected namespace` occurs because your streaming thread called `emit()` after the client was disconnected. If you want to avoid this error, you have to make your thread smarter. Whenever the `disconnect` handler for the client is invoked, the thread must be informed of this so that it stops the streaming.

Then when the client reconnects, it should request a new streaming thread to be started by the server.